# How do I change default excel extension in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm getting hard drive images from someone that I am tweaking with my own software.  But, The image has Office 2007.  I've noticed that when I try and save an Excel document, it defaults to *.xls, not the newer *.xlsx extension that I want.  Now, I've searched online and everywhere I look, it says

1. Click on the office icon.
2. Select Excel Options button.
3. Select Save from the left pane.
4. Select the extension under the "Save files in this format:" drop down.
5. Select OK.

I do all this and doing a save will default to *.xlsx extension.  However, when I close and reopen excel, it's back to square one--defaulting to *.xls.  Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps the image is not updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, it may be set as part of the group policy: [(see here)](http://www.mydigitallife.info/change-office-2007-default-file-save-formats-and-extensions-using-group-policy-gpo/)

> In the left pane of the Group Policy Management Console, double-click User Configuration,
>   and then double-click Administrative Templates (Classic Administrative Templates (ADM) in
>   Windows Vista). Then follows the following steps to set and change the default saving file
>   format in Office 2007 programs.
>
> To change default file save options in Office Excel 2007
>
> ```
> Double-click Microsoft Office Excel 2007, double-click Excel Options, and click Save.
> In the right pane, right-click Save Excel files as, and select Properties.
> In Save files in this format, select Enabled.
> In the drop-down box, select a default file save format.
> Click Apply to save the settings.
> ```